# Multiple file upload together with excel form

Tags: php, forms

We presently have a form that when submitted the user responses are emailed to us as an attached excel file.  We also have another form that allows the user to upload multiple files of various types which are then emailed to us as attachments.  However we have been unable to combine the two into one form, so that we can receive an email with both types of attachments. We are beginners...

Below is:
1. The existing form which attaches the single excel content
2. the existing mailer.php
3. the existing form which uploads multiple files

**1. excel content form**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); 

ob_start();


$taxyear = $_POST['taxyear'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$tfn = $_POST['tfn'];
$director1 = $_POST['director1'];
$director2 = $_POST['director2'];
$email = $_POST['email'];


?>

<html>
<body> 
<form>
<table width="720" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">

  <tr align="center" valign="top">
    <td height="1730">COMPANY RETURN
      <table width="702" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="6" align="left" class="whiteonred" >Company <strong><? echo $taxyear; ?> </strong></td>
        </tr>
          <tr class="excel7" style="height:18.0pt;">
          <td colspan="4" align="left" class="centgothicstd" ><strong>PRINCIPAL DETAILS </strong></td>
          <td colspan="2" align="right" class="centgothicsm">&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>
          <tr style="height:18.0pt;">
            <td align="left" class="centgothicsm" >COMPANY NAME &amp; TFN</td>
            <td colspan="3" align="left" class="borders"><strong><? echo $company; ?></strong></td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left" class="borders"><strong><? echo $tfn; ?></strong></td>

          </tr>
          <tr style="height:18.0pt;">
            <td width="213" align="left" class="centgothicsm" style="height:18.0pt;">DIRECTOR NAMES</td>
            <td colspan="3" align="left" class="borders"><? echo $director1; ?></td>
            <td colspan="2" align="left" class="borders"><? echo $director2; ?></td>

          </tr>
        <tr style="height:18.0pt;">
          <td width="213" align="left" class="centgothicsm" style="height:18.0pt;">EMAIL ADDRESS</td>
          <td colspan="5" align="left" class="borders"><? echo $email; ?></td>

        </tr>

      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

$FILE_CONTENTS = ob_get_contents(); 

ob_clean(); 

include("mailer.php"); 

$recipient = "darren@eto.net.au"; 

$subject = "Company submission"; 

$myEmail = new EPDEV_Emailer($recipient, $email, $subject); 

$myEmail->addFile("{$company}-{$taxyear}.xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel", $FILE_CONTENTS); 

$myEmail->send(); 

Header("Location: thankyouapplic.htm");
?>
```

**2. the mailer.php code **

```
<?php 

class EPDEV_Emailer 
{ 
    var $message; 
    var $FILES; 
    var $EMAIL; 

    function EPDEV_Emailer($to_address, $from_address, $subject, $reply_address=null, $mailer=null, $custom_header=null) 
    { 
        $this->EMAIL = array( 
            "to" => $to_address, 
            "from" => $from_address, 
            "subject" => $subject, 
            "reply" => (empty($reply_address) ? $from_address : $reply_address), 
            "mailer" => (empty($mailer) ? "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() : $mailer), 
            "header" => (empty($custom_header) ? "" : $custom_header), 
            "boundary" => "_mimeboundary_".md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), 1)) 
            ); 

        $this->message = ""; 

        $this->FILES = array(); 
    } 

    function addFile($filename, $type=null, $filecontents=null) 
    { 
        if ($filecontents !== null) 
        { 
            $index = count($this->FILES); 
            $this->FILES[$index]['data'] = chunk_split(base64_encode($filecontents)); 
            $this->FILES[$index]['name'] = basename($filename); 

            if (empty($type)) 
                $this->FILES[$index]['mime'] = mime_content_type($filename); 
            else 
                $this->FILES[$index]['mime'] = $type; 
        } 
        else if (file_exists($filename)) 
        { 
            $index = count($this->FILES); 
            $this->FILES[$index]['data'] = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($filename))); 
            $this->FILES[$index]['name'] = basename($filename); 

            if (empty($type)) 
                $this->FILES[$index]['mime'] = mime_content_type($filename); 
            else 
                $this->FILES[$index]['mime'] = $type; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            $this->Error_Handle("File specified -- {$filename} -- does not exist."); 
        } 
    } 



    function addText($text) 
    { 
        $this->message .= $text; 
    } 


    function getHeader() 
    { 
        $header = "From: {$this->EMAIL['from']}\r\n" 
                . "Reply-To: {$this->EMAIL['reply']}\r\n" 
                . "X-Mailer: {$this->EMAIL['mailer']}\r\n" 
                . "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" 
                . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{$this->EMAIL['boundary']}\";\r\n"; 

        return $header; 
    } 

    function getEmail() 
    {     
        $content .= "--{$this->EMAIL['boundary']}\r\n" 
                . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n" 
                . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n" 
                . $this->message . "\r\n"; 

        if (!empty($this->FILES)) 
        { 
            foreach($this->FILES as $file) 
            { 
                $content .= "--{$this->EMAIL['boundary']}\r\n" 
                . "Content-Type: {$file['mime']}; name=\"{$file['name']}\"\r\n" 
                . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" 
                . "Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n" 
                . $file['data'] . "\r\n"; 
            } 
        } 

        $content .= "--{$this->EMAIL['boundary']}--\r\n"; 


        return $content; 
    } 

    function send() 
    { 
        $result = mail($this->EMAIL['to'], $this->EMAIL['subject'], $this->getEmail(), $this->getHeader()); 

        if (!$result) 
            $this->Error_Handle("The email failed to send."); 
    } 


    function Error_Handle($error) 
    { 
        die($error); 
    } 
}
```

**3. the upload form**

```
<body>
<td height="353" colspan="9" align="left" valign="top">

  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="send" method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="send" />
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
    <tr>
      <td width="300" align="center">&nbsp;</td>

      <table width="500" height="407" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
          <td width="120" align="left" class="indextextlight">Name:</td>
          <td colspan="2"><input name="fname" type="text" class="indextextlight" size="30" /></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="120" height="24" align="left" class="indextextlight">E-mail:</td>
          <td colspan="2"><label>
            <input name="email" type="text" class="indextextlight" size="30" />
          </label></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="120" align="left" class="indextextlight">Telephone:</td>
          <td colspan="2"><label>
            <input name="tel" type="text" class="indextextlight" id="tel" value="" size="15" />
          </label></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="120" align="left" valign="top" class="indextextlight">Message:

            </td>
          <td colspan="2" valign="top"><textarea name="comments" " id="comments" cols="45" rows="4"></textarea></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="120" valign="middle" class="indextextlight">Upload Files:</td>
          <td colspan="2"><p>
            <input name="attachment[]" type="file" multiple="" class="indextextlight" size="42">
            <br />
            <span class="centgothicmini">              note - hold the Ctrl key to select multiple files</span><br />
            <span class="centgothicmini">              note - max total size of all files can not  exceed 10mb</span></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="120" align="left" class="indextextlight">Send:</td>
          <td colspan="2" align="left"><input type="image" name="submit" value="Send Email" src="images/btnSubmit.gif" /></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="120" class="indextextlight">Result:</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="header"><?php
/* Mailer with Attachments */

$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
global $action;

function showform(){
?></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="indextextlight">&nbsp;</td>
          <td colspan="2" class="header">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="3" align="right" valign="baseline" class="footer"><span class="footerheadings">&nbsp;</span> © 2009-13 BC Accountants Australia Pty Ltd</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

  </form>   
  <script type="text/javascript">
var frmvalidator  = new Validator("send");
frmvalidator.addValidation("fname","req","Please enter your Name");
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","maxlen=50");
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req");
frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email");
frmvalidator.addValidation("tel","maxlen=15");
frmvalidator.addValidation("tel","numeric");

</script>      
  <?php
}

function sendMail() {
  if (!isset ($_POST['email'])) { //Oops, forgot your email addy!
    die ("<p>Oops!  You forgot to fill out the email address! Click on the back arrow to go back</p>");
  }
  else {

    $fname = stripslashes($_POST['fname']);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['tel'];
    $comments = stripslashes($_POST['comments']);
    $headers .= "\n";

    //Uniqid session
    $strSid = md5(uniqid(time()));

    //Let's start our headers
    $headers = "From: $fname<" . $_POST['email'] . ">\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: <" . $_POST['email'] . ">\n"; 
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";  
    $headers .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

    $headers .= "--".$strSid."\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";  

    /* Add our message, in this case it's plain text.  You could also add HTML by changing the Content-Type to text/html */
    $headers .= "<table>";

    $headers .= "<tr><td>CONTACT FORM</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
    $headers .= "<tr><td>Check for attachments</td><td>&nbsp;</td>      </tr>";

    $headers .= "<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td > </td>
    </tr>";

    $headers .= "<tr>
    <td >Name:  " . strip_tags($_POST["fname"]) . "</td><td >&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>";

    $headers .= "<tr>
    <td>Email:  " . strip_tags($_POST["email"]) . "</td><td >&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>";

    $headers .= "<tr>
    <td>Phone:  " . strip_tags($_POST["phone"]) . "</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>";

    $headers .= "<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td > </td>
    </tr>";

    $headers .= "<tr>
    <td>MESSAGE</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";

    $headers .= "<tr> <td COLSPAN = '2'>" . strip_tags($_POST["comments"]) . "</td>
    </tr>"; 

    $headers .= "<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td > </td>
    </tr>";

    $headers .= "</table>";
    $headers .= "</body></html>";
    $headers .= "\n"; 



    //**multi attach**//
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);$i++)
    {
    if($_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i] != "")
    {
        $file_name = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i];
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$i])));
        $headers .= "--".$strSid."\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\n\tname=\"" . $file_name . "\"\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n\tfilename=\"" . $file_name . "\"\n\n";
        $headers .= $data."\n\n"; //The base64 encoded message
    }

    }
    $headers .= "\n"; 
    $headers .= "------=MIME_BOUNDRY_main_message--\n"; 
    $subject .= "Contact Form";
    // send the message
    mail("darrenmillbca@gmail.com", $subject, $message, $headers); 
    print "Mail sent. Thank you!";
$to = $email; 

$subject = "Contact Form"; 

$message = '
<html>
<body>

<p>Dear '; 
$message .= $fname;
$message .= '</p>
<p>Thankyou for your message. </p>
<p>Our staff will get back to you shortly. </p>

<p>Kind Regards <br />
  <br />
  </p>

</body>
</html>
';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To:' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: darrenmillbca@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);



  }
}

switch ($action) {
  case "send":
    sendMail();
    showForm();
    break;
  default:
    showForm();
}


?>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is quite a significant change here, so I'll try my best to make it simple for you guys. Your excel content form makes use of an *email wrapper* (mailer.php) which converts attaching files to an email to just $myEmail->addFile("file name","mimetype","file content"). The upload form on the other hand is not using this wrapper and is instead generating a whole email seperately. So you'll want to focus on moving your uploads to utilising the wrapper; that's moving content from the uploads form to the excel form.

So, our focus is with the following block from the uploads file:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);$i++)
    {
    if($_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i] != "")
    {
        $file_name = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i];
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$i])));
        $headers .= "--".$strSid."\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;\n\tname=\"" . $file_name . "\"\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n\tfilename=\"" . $file_name . "\"\n\n";
        $headers .= $data."\n\n"; //The base64 encoded message
    }
```

Which is saying 'for each file upload, write it into the email we're building up'. Instead of this, we want to do 'for each file upload, attach it using the wrapper'. That would be done like so:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);$i++){
        if($_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i] != "")
        {
            $file_name = $_FILES["attachment"]["name"][$i];
            $data = file_get_contents($_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
            $myEmail->addFile($file_name,"application/octet-stream",$data);
        }
}
```

For this to work, the above code would go in your excel form right after the existing $myEmail->addFile call. In other words, right after you attach your excel sheet, look for any attachments, then add those to the email too:

```
$myEmail->addFile("{$company}-{$taxyear}.xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel", $FILE_CONTENTS); 
 // Drop it right here.
$myEmail->send();
```

So far so good - at this point, your excel form can *handle* multiple uploads, but it can't *create* them. To fix that, you'll then want to start transferring the html that allows your users to upload files over to your excel form. That's this part:

```
<tr>
          <td width="120" valign="middle" class="indextextlight">Upload Files:</td>
          <td colspan="2"><p>
            <input name="attachment[]" type="file" multiple="" class="indextextlight" size="42">
            <br />
            <span class="centgothicmini">              note - hold the Ctrl key to select multiple files</span><br />
            <span class="centgothicmini">              note - max total size of all files can not  exceed 10mb</span></td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
```

A simple thing you could do is dump that wherever it fits on your excel form and as a result your excel form should then accept multiple uploads. From there, all that is required is transferring any other fields you want from upload to excel :)

Comment: Thanks Luke. Unfortunately I'm still having problems, I think because the content and upload are gathered from the user in an initial html file. The issue now is how to pass the uploaded files to the excel php file ?  This is the initial file;

Comment: You'd merge the two html files together by copying at least the above section of html from the upload file to the excel one - i.e. make your two forms one; if that's not possible then you'd have to put e.g. the excel file in some temporary file (file_put_contents may be useful to you) and pull it from the file (file_get_contents) in the uploads form

Comment: Yes tried merging but it failed, at any rate we want to keep the php code hidden, as we've recently been copied.  Will try the second suggestion. Pls email me if u r available for fee.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't provide the ability to mail you directly unfortunately.

Comment: Do you guys have a website?

Comment: www.eto.net.au, www.bcaccountants.com.au